# Уведомления с авито в Telegram

Tags: парсер, telegram, уведомления

Хочу создать оповещения о новых объявлениях с Авито в телеграмм. Хочется видеть их именно в мессенджере. Можете подробно объяснить, какие ресурсы понадобятся для этой реализации и какие материалы нужно изучить по данной теме т.к. сам новичок и доселе не имел дел с такими задачами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задаете очень общий вопрос. *Здесь такое не любят*.

Дам Вам направление, хотя и подобные вопросы очень специфичны, я лишь могу предложить стек, которым воспользовался бы сам.
Язык - [Python](https://www.python.org/), предпочтительно **3** версии.

**Парсер**: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), отлично справляется со статическим парсингом. Если этого окажется недостаточно и окажется что страницы генерируются JS(ом), то все сложнее. Там нужен будет Selenium, который отлично работает в связке с Chrome.
Читайте эти статьи:

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/328800/ (рус.)
- https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python (англ.)
- https://medium.com/@pyzzled/running-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python-3f42d1f5ff1d (англ.)

**API** для Телеграм выбирайте сами, я с ними особо не работал, так что посоветовать что то сложно.

Если появится необходимость в **сервере** смотрите в сторону [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Также не любят, когда отвечают на вопросы, на которые не стоит отвечать и ставят профилактические минусы.

Comment: @AK, самый плохой вопрос - это то который не был задан. Вы не в праве решать на какие вопросы стоит или не стоит отвечать.